# Selenium + javascriptExecutor issue in InternetExplorer

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written the following code for javascript executer that opens a browser pop-up and a code to accept that popup.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('del7757_7540').click();");             
            try {
                Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                String AlertText = alert.getText();
                System.out.println(AlertText);
                alert.accept();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("no alert");
            }
```

The code works fine in Mozilla Firefox. When I try to do I in Internet Explorer, it won't work. 
Let  me explain what happens. The browser popup appears and then gets stuck on that page without moving to next step i.e. it doesnot accept the popup. While I used debugger, I noticed that it gets stuck on javascriptExecuter. The browser doesnot hang. It just gets stuck on the popup menu and thats it. The debugger mode shows that the control is never passed to try catch or below it.

Comment: so if the IE browser is stuck at the javascript executor maybe it is not identifying the elementId as such try giving some other element identifier.

Comment: @igniteram1 No that cannot be. It found the elementId that is why it clicked on that elementId and that popup appear. Had it not found how could it have showed the popup that is only possible after clicking the elementId?

Comment: @igniteram1 it executes the JavascriptExecuter and then never moves to next line of code.

Comment: then try removing JavascriptExecuter and identify the popup normally, coz it has been observed that IE has issues with javascripts. If it works like this then it should work for firefox as well. It is always advisable to develop your automation scripts keeping IE as your base browser(if your application needs IE as the primary browser). If you plan like this then you would have minimum difficulties with other advanced browsers like chrome and firefox.

Comment: Why are you using JSE to get an element by ID and then click it? Just use the regular driver to do this.

Comment: @JeffC I tried with the regular driver command but it wouldnot click on that element in Internet Explorer. But it did work in Mozilla firefox. I tried everything : by css, xpath, id, tagname. But it wouldnot click on that element in Internet Explorer. Do you think you could suggest something?

Comment: I'd have to see the page to find out why it might not be working.

Comment: @JeffC I am afraid I cannot share you the page. It cannot be accessed from outside as it is hosted locally.

Comment: @igniteram1 I need it in Internet Explorer. While trying with other methods of selenium to locate the element, it would not click the element. Now when I do it via JavaScriptExecuter, the element is found but couldnot move to next line of code. It like going in loop inside the JavaScriptExecuter infinitelly.

Comment: @igniteram1 could you suggest something. I tried using multithreading. This time the control is transferred to Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(). Now, it control won't move to another line of code.  Previously it control didnot even passed to Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert()

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this and let me know if it works-

```
   @Test
   public void testAlert() throws InterruptedException {  

   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('del7757_7540').click();"); 
   Thread.sleep(5000); // I generally do not use/prefer thread.sleep
   System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());                         
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

   }
```

Comment: Still no luck. Same problem